# Trigger multiply from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, sql-update

i need to create a trigger that multiply two fields from two tables, but i have no idea of how to do it, so let's see if you can help me.

Two tables,

Products (product_name, price)

Orders (product_name (foreign key),units_ordered)

I need to add another field on table the Orders that multiply price from Products and units_ordered from Orders, so : total_price = price (from products) X units_ordered (from Orders)

Thanks in advance, and sorry for my bad english.
Regards

Comment: Can you show some code? Do you know how to write triggers at all, or are you just unsure about doing this particular task?

Comment: Do you need a trigger or a view? Do you want to have a field in table orders that has the outcome of the multiplication when a record is inserted in it?

Comment: I have read a little about the triggers, but don't know how to use them in this example, the all code is not in english, but that's not important, the only tables that matter are those two. :S

Comment: Yes koriander, that's what i need, not a view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need trigger at all. And also you don't need to add another column for the total price as it is already redundant.

If you want their total prices, just do it during the projection of records. Example

```
SELECT  a.Product_Name,
        a.Price,
        b.units_ordered,
        a.Price * b.units_ordered AS TotalPrice 
FROM    Products a
        INNER JOIN Orders b
            ON a.Product_name = b.Product_name
```

or you can create a `VIEW` out of your `SELECT` statement. Example,

```
CREATE VIEW ProductOrder
AS
SELECT  a.Product_Name,
        a.Price,
        b.units_ordered,
        a.Price * b.units_ordered AS TotalPrice 
FROM    Products a
        INNER JOIN Orders b
            ON a.Product_name = b.Product_name
```

and selecting from the view,

```
SELECT * FROM ProductOrder
```

But if you really want to add another column, still trigger is not an option. You only need to update the values for that column using `UPDATE` and joining of the two tables. Assuming your new column is called `TotalPrice` on table `Orders.

```
UPDATE  Orders a
        INNER JOIN Products b
            ON a.Product_name = b.Product_name
SET     a.TotalPrice = a.units_ordered * b.Price
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but that's not exactly what i need, i need that the field takes the value of the multiply of the two fields, not a view :(

Comment: Tennosuke! Why are you using a trigger? are you trying to persist the value of total price? I agree with J W it is redundant and his solution is good if all you want is just the total price. Not sure what you are trying to achive with trigger? Regards!

Comment: I read your comment, I am not fimiliar with MYSQL syntax, can help you with SQL Server!