# Multiply and update two valors from two different tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have to multiply two valors between two different tables.

```
TABLE NAME match_serie_a
        id   journee     equipe_A     equipe_B   quote_1   quote_N  quote_2   resultat    date
         2    38         Juventus       Lecce      1.25      3.5     6.9          1      2020-06-27

TABLE NAME pari 
        id_Joueur      id_Match     montant_pari     type_pari    Gagne    montant_gain
            4              2            10               1         oui        NULL
```

Now, i should multiply "montant_pari" from the table "pari" with "quote_1" from table "match_serie_a" and stock the result in "montant_gain".

What is the best request for do that?

Comment: A multi table update see manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html

Comment: This looks like a case of poor schema design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method uses a correlated subquery:

```
update table2 t2
    set montant_gain = (select t2.montant_pari * t1.quote_1
                        from table1 t1
                        where t1.id = t2.id_match  -- I am guessing this is used to match rows
                       );
```

Comment: Please explain your DVs.  It is very rude not to comment.  Especially to a user that is so knowledgeable, dedicated and experienced.  This answer looks good enough to me.  If you do not provide a justification for the DV, I will be neutralizing the attack (and you merely waste your own rep).

Comment: How about a JOIN @Gordon? https://stackoverflow.com/a/15989584/2943403 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/34463077/2943403

Comment: @mickmackusa downvotes are not are not evil nor are they a attack on the person. Furthermore, the person posting the answer or question for that matter shouldn't matter whether you upvote or downvote, it's about the content. I can't tell you why it's downvotes, but people generally don't vote and comment because people relatiate.

Comment: You aren't the retaliatory type.  No comment mean you have no way of fixing what they "believe" is wrong.  The DV help no one -- not you, not the OP, not researchers, not themselves.  It is pure toxicity.

Comment: If you hover over the downvote button you'll see a tooltip explaining what a downvote means, and it helps future visitors by indicating what is good and bad, whether you agree with that downvote is a different thing

Comment: Downvoting correct answers only confuses the OP and thousands of future researchers.  It actively harms what Stack Overflow intends to do -- help researchers.  If there was something DV-worthy about this post, it is worth explaining so that the post can be improved or removed.